# DAO and Connections

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

Where I should open and close connections to repositories? In article "[Dont repeat the DAO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html)" written:

> The DAO is not responsible for handling transactions, sessions, or
>   connections. These are handled outside the DAO to achieve flexibility.

But some people suggest me to inject `@Resource DataSource` object into DAO classes and handle all connections inside DAO methods...i.e. every CRUD operation should open and close connection to repository.

Comment: We don't manage connections inside DAO since you can have multiple DAO to fetch entities using the same opened connection.

Answer (score 6):

Take the recommendation from the article.

Preferably you want your application container to manage Resources and connection pooling. If your connection has transaction management configured, then the container will be able to manage your transaction (hence no need to open connection and do commits).

If you're managing connection and transaction yourself, open the connection first, enable transaction and pass the opened connection to the DAO, commit transaction, then close connection (outside of the DAO).

Once your service finished with all DAO's, close the connection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, I manage transactions, connections myself. `open the connection first, enable transaction and pass the opened connection to the DAO` - Can I do this thing in service layer? Or I need to create some wrapper classes to hide this all low-level mechanisms (opening connections, transactions) and use this wrapper classes inside service-layer? Also, I use Java EE5, so can I use EJB's for DAOs?

Comment: To answer **all** of your question: Yes!

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Spring to manage the data sources.

Configure the data source bean in your application context xml. Autowire it to the DAO and then use Spring to handle the transactions with the `@Transactional` annotation on the DAO class.

You also need `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in your application context.

If you are using Hibernate you can do the same by configuring the `SessionFactory` in your application context.

Comment: sorry, but I don't use nor Spring not Hibernate

Comment: DAO should not be responsible for handling connections but it depends on them. @MyTitle If you don't use Spring or Hibernate, then you have to handle those connections in the business logic layer for transactions. After fetching one connection from the datasource , the business layer component will pass it into your DAOs. Actually Spring already provides some handy XXXDAOSupport classes, it works really well with datasouce.

Comment: @GavinXiong thanks, after your comment I understand this process more clearly. And second question (may be offtopic): what about using EJB's as DAO objects? And then reusing this DAO (EJBs in fact) in another EJBs (i.e. in service layer).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you can use spring for managing transactions but at the same time keep in mind that managing transactions is not a duty of DAOs. They should be handled in your service layer which is responsible for managing business logic.

Comment: Should I handle connections (also as transactions)  inside service layer? I.e service-layer will open connection, then open transaction, then use DAO objects for some business logic, commit transaction and close connection? It's true?

Comment: No, DB conections will be handled in DAO layer only. Its only transactions which will be handled by service layer.